# How can I integrate two different servers like Angular and NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, angular, server

I'm new in Angular and NodeJS. I finished all the basic documentation, and now I'm doing tutorials. My question is about the architecture.

Following the angular tutorial, you create a new server:

```
ng new new-project
```

That creates a whole server listening to port 4200, you learn and work with angular, learn about directives, etc.

Then you create a server with node, configure routes, etc.
But how these two servers live together?
What do you recommend me to join them?

[This is a node server. The angular part are just two files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpduU.png)

[This is the server created with ng serve. The angular part is so much complicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjWSa.png)

Comment: What do you mean by 2 servers? Angular are on front-end and Nodejs are on Backend. Unless you use SSR (server-side rendering) method for angular you can run it on server (not build it, still you place it on server but not run it directly with `ng-serve`).

And what do you mean by Join?

Comment: Thanks for answering. When you run that command (ng new) it creates a whole server itself, it is already a server that you can run and browse. But I have another node server already functioning with other stuff already developed. 
My question is about, how can I add all my angular new project to my already existent Node server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular project is not a server. Angular is framework to create front-end page/app. Angular-cli command `ng serve` is used to build application and start a web server on localhost. 
When you build your page with angular use angular-cli command `ng build --prod` to build your page ( [more info about ng build command](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)). The build artifacts will be stored in the `dist/` directory of your project.

If you want to host angular page with node - copy file from *projektFolder/dist* to catalog when node can have access to copy files. In node you can use express library to host static files:

```
app.use('/myangularproject', express.static('myangularproject')) //host static files`
```

[More info about hosted static files in node and express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

**EDIT**

You use Angular CLI to build an angular application. This is an additional tool for working with angular and you do not have to use it.

> Angular cli is a command line interface to scaffold and build angular apps using nodejs style (commonJs) modules. Not only it provides you scalable project structure, instead it handles all common tedious tasks for you out of the box

**ng serve**

`ng serve` is a tool from angular cli. When you call this command your project is build in memory and serve it via webpack-dev-server. **It is used for quick preview and development of the project**. If this command is confusing for you then you can use the npm script `npm start`.

> The CLI supports running a live browser reload experience to users by running ng serve. This will compile the application upon file saves and reload the browser with the newly compiled application. This is done by hosting the application in memory and serving it via [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#webpack-dev-server). [doc](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/afbddfe348e532c48d272cf9b4273b9ef7af06c7/docs/documentation/stories/disk-serve.md)

**ng build**

`ng build` compiles the application into an output directory.

> Compiles an Angular app into an output directory named dist/ at the given output path. Must be executed from within a workspace directory.

When you use command `ng new` Angular CLI add all necessary files to develop your application. Some of them are used to configure the project e.g `tslint.json`, `tsconfig.json`, `angular.json` ... Do not host these files only result files from the use of the `ng build` command (`/dist` directory).

Angular CLI compiles your project into several files (try `ng build` and look how many files do you have in `/dist`. You must host all of them. These are static files. You do not need a special server like php files. You can host them using a regular file server. I don't know what you concern use in the node to host static files.  If they use `express` you can use `express.static()`. More info at the top.

Comment: I understand that Angular is not a server and it's a front-end javascript based framework. But I don't understand then why with `ng serve` you start a server. What kind of server is that ? So deploy my angular project into another node server is as easy as copy `projectFolder/dist` into the node server?

Comment: To be more clear, in my Node server the angular part is composed by two files, one service and one controller. But in this new server made using the CLI I have plenty of files, libraries and .json files. My concern is working with complex server and then how I make it work in my previous node server?

Comment: I have edited my post. Maybe he'll be more helpful now

Comment: Thank you very much, it is, yes.